# Start browser process as Windows user

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core

I have a windowless wpf app that's taking messages from an asp.net core app via signalr and displaying them to the user. I also have a NotifyIcon that has one right click option to open the web app in the browser (Process.Start). The problem is, the web app is using Windows Auth and the process is started as the computer and not the user, thus not being authenticated. How do I get the process to start as the user?

I can't use process.UserName, because that requires a password, and I don't want the user to enter the password everytime. I've also tried process.LoadUserProfile but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What is "the process" that "started as the computer"? You'd better configure this to start when a user logs in (Windows supports multiple ways of achieving that), and then it runs as the user.

Comment: The process is the wpf app, and it’s starting under the users startup folder.

Comment: Unless it's a service, i would expect an app which is just added to the current user's startup folder to run in their context. Why isn't it?

Comment: I am using a startup project to install/uninstall the app and have already tried switching ‘installallusers’ from true to false and that didn’t help either. Would it install differently if it started from their startup folder vs from me just installing the msi manually?